# Вывести названия над линиями javafx

Tags: javafx

В Root добавляются линии. Надо что-бы над линиями примерно в середине было их название, то есть что-бы названия были под тем же углом что и линии.

Comment: Root - это что?

Comment: Group root = new Group();

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.